# Plot a simple network graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I have a data frame as

```
mydf <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5), MatchedID = c(3,4,2,5,1), Weight = c(12,45,5,19,9))
```

I wish to plot a network graph showing relation between ID and matchedID and weights as strength of that relationship.
What is the best way to represent this with labels? I like the ones at https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(mydf, directed=TRUE)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "weight", value = mydf$Weight)
plot(g, edge.width = E(g)$weight/5, edge.label=E(g)$weight)
```

[image]

Or use ggplot2

```
library(GGally)
library(sna)
library(network)
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% 
    spread(MatchedID, Weight, fill = 0) %>%  
    select(-ID) %>%
    network(names.eval = "weights", ignore.eval = FALSE) %>% 
    ggnet2(label = TRUE, edge.label = "weights")
```

[image]